# Does rename_column in Rails ActiveRecord Migration preserve the old column data type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to run a rails migration where in I am changing just the column name. So, this rails takes care of keeping the same `data type` as the old column or tries to make a guess based on the `column content`?

```
def change
   rename_column :marks, :percent, :percentage
end
```

The old type was `decimal` and after migration it still remains `decimal`.
Just I wanted to know the type was preserved because the existing values were `decimal` or it was because of the `old data type`.

Comment: The question you asked can be answered by just applying the migrations. _type was preserved because the existing values were decimal or it was because of the old data type_, yes both are true or there can be many. column renaming should not play with actual meta data and data stored in actual column. That's pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename_column is meant for only simply changing the name of the  column without thinking about the datatype.

In the given migration you are changing only the name from percent to percentage so rails doesn't care about the datatype and only changes the name of the column. There is no change in the datatype, it will intact as it is. whether it is decimal, float, string etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `rename_column`  is only renaming the name of column with 3 parameters. `change_column` would change the type

```
def change
   change_column :marks, :percent, :text
end
```